# Re-sharing posts from an app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, share

When I am posting to my wall directly, then my friends have an option to "re-share" the post by clicking on "Share" link (last one in the list of actions: Like * Comment * Share). However, when I post from an application, there is no "Share" link and only Like and Comment actions are available.

Is there a way to change application or application preferences to enable direct re-sharing for posts from applications?

Answer (score 1):

You can post a "[Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/)" to User's wall with a "link"-field to the Original post like `"http://www.facebook.com/{{$fb_id}}"` and you can add a "message" to that as well.

**UPD**: for reSharing a "Picture" you either "generate" a link like `"http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid={{$fb_id}}"` or request Picture via GraphAPI and use it's `"link"` field. this is valid for other FB-Graph-Types.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it is done In [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) do this..

```
post me/feed
message : YOUR_MESSAGE
link : link to share
actions : {name: "share", link: "linktoshare"}
```

Refer these

1. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts
2. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android